# Indistinguishability of [f] and [s] on phone - citation?

Tags: phonetics, speech-recognition

I have long felt that [f] and [s] are hard to tell apart on the phone, especially when spelling out words letter by letter.  As a non linguist (but audio engineer) it seems to me that the frequencies required to distinguish them are usually higher than the bandwidth of the phone codec.

Today I fell foul of this in a most unfortunate way, and managed to get a parking penalty charge because the automated pay-by-phone system for the car park registered the wrong license plate.

In order to help me prepare the case to contest my parking ticket - can anyone provide me with a citation for this fact?

Comment: Related: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9678/why-is-f-ambiguous-between-f-and-s-after-saying-the-word-three

Comment: Well done stack exchange, desired result obtained - I got my penalty charge cancelled!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.linguistics.ucsb.edu/faculty/gordon/fricativeacoustics.pdf) may be useful for its collection of references. [This paper](http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/plab/CPLWorkingPapers/pdfs/wpcpl12-Jongman.pdf) is a single simple read. The problem is that the spectral properties of fricatives are usually reported in terms of the frequency of the spectral peak, where /f/ and /s/ are clearly different but also above the cutoff frequency for the phone. Another part of the black box that you're up against is that the ASR system doesn't involve a small, phonetically trained human making spectrograms, so you'd need to come up with a reason to think that the system they used has problems. (It isn't generally the case that nobody can distinguish [s] and [f] on the phone, and I think that some ASR systems introduce problems, so learning how ASR works could be helpful).

[EDIT]

The citation for the Jongman paper is Jongman, A., Wayland, R., & Wong, S. (1998). 'Acoustic characteristics of English fricatives: I. Static cues'. *Working Papers of the Cornell Phonetics Laboratory*. 12: 195-205. The current URL is http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/plab/paper/wpcpl12-Jongman.pdf.

Comment: +1. I would add that, while not all [s] and [f] sounds are ambiguous to humans on the phone all of the time, they are more likely to be confused in the very context in question--word-finally. See my answer to the related question linked in my comment above.

Comment: Note, too, that in ordinary speech the context provides strong cues for distinction; for instance, it is hard to imagine a context in which *sail* and *fail* are equally likely. But reciting an arbitrary string of letters provides  no context which might resolve an ambiguity.

Comment: The second paper is no longer available. Can you provide a link to a different source?